# Mat drawer content scroll not working properly

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design, angular-material

I have one header, one sidenav and one footer component as a shared module for my website.

[image]

I am trying to create a form to search product inside sidenav content and for that I have created a layout module which look like below.

default.html

```
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"></app-header>

<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]="sideBarOpen">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

default.scss

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
mat-drawer {
  width: 350px;
}

mat-drawer-container {
  height: 100%;
}

mat-drawer-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Everything is working fine but when I scroll down my search form page, footer overlaps my buttons like below.

[image]

Can somebody tell me where I am doing wrong? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

PS: I am not good in CSS so kind of hard to understand. I am also searching for solution on google meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the two buttons (red and blue) are on your search form page and it is scrolable.

Try to apply `padding-bottom:<the height of footer>px` on the container of search page.